# Problems with the compilation and installation of the Apache HTTP Server on Unix

Tags: apache, unix, compilation, installation

When I try "Configuring the source tree" in the link below:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html#upgrading
I get the following error and can't see the problem any ideas?

Thanks

$ sudo CC="pgcc" CFLAGS="-O2" \

> ./configure --prefix=/sw/pkg/apache \
>   --enable-ldap=shared \
>   --enable-lua=shared
>   [sudo] password for dosullivan: 
>   checking for chosen layout... Apache
>   checking for working mkdir -p... yes
>   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
>   checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
>   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   configure: 
>   configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
>   configure: 
>   checking for APR... yes
>     setting CPP to "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -E"
>     adding "-pthread" to CFLAGS
>     setting CPPFLAGS to " -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE"
>     setting LDFLAGS to " "
>   configure: 
>   configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
>   configure: 
>   checking for APR-util... yes
>   checking for gcc... pgcc
>   checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/home/dosullivan/httpd-2.4.4':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>   See`config.log' for more details

Answer (score 0):

It appears that 'pgcc' is not the name of your compiler. Are you sure you didn't mean to use 'gcc'?

Basically, the configure command is trying to produce a 'hello world' style program just to make sure that it has access to a working compiler.

Comment: $ CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-O2" \
> ./configure --prefix=/sw/pkg/apache \
> --enable-ldap=shared \
> --enable-lua=shared I tried this and nothing happened? Sorry I am not used to this program at all.

Comment: Did it produce a file named 'Makefile'? If so, it worked. Then you should be able to compile it by issuing the command 'make'.